# How do I calculate the running variance?

Tags: variance, mean, real-time

I only get one value at a time in the system that I am developing. However whenever I get my first value I should already be able to calculate a variance.
Every time I get a new value I should recalculate the variance.
One important note is that I can't save any previous values, I should thus be able to calculate variances "on the fly".

[Something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37830174/4806970) is what I would need but for variances.

Thank you

Comment: Please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=online+variance.

Comment: You could update the estimate using a recursive formula.  However I don't follow your premise that you can estimate a variance based on only the first value.

Comment: @Michael Use the Normal MLE for variance: it works even with one value (and is zero, but so what?).

Comment: @whuber I guess that is fine for the algorithm as long as you don't take the first estimate seriously.

Comment: @whuber that looks very complicated....

Comment: @whuber the solution described at the other question didn't work for me. I exactly implemented that code and it didn't work. I guess it is because in my case n is always equal to 1.

Comment: This brings us back to @Michael Chernick's comment: your situation makes little sense in that case.  Exactly what do you mean by "n is always equal to 1"?  After you have obtained a second value, you have *two* values.  When the third comes in, you have *three*--and so on.  The whole point of the duplicate is that to update the variance, as you request, you don't need to save the previous $n-1$ values.  But you do need to save a little bit of information!

Comment: @whuber no because when the second value comes in I have to "throw away" the first value. I can only keep one value at a time (i.e. the current value) and the result of my calculation.

Comment: And that is *precisely* what any "online" algorithm does, such as the one in the duplicate.  In fact, you don't need to keep the current data value--you only need to keep (a) the current variance, (b) the current mean, and (c) the current count.  That's all.